# nuxt3 nuxt-link dynamic query parameter: only the first time refreshing the page

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

in app.vue template header section:

```
<input type="search" v-model="q" />
<nuxt-link :to="{path: '/search', query: {qry: q}}">Search</nuxt-link>

..
..
<nuxt-page />
```

in search.vue

```
<script setup>

let r = useRoute();
console.log(r.query.qry);

</script>
```

As result, only the first time, I can get the r.query.qry

After that, click the search link, got nothing. Only if press F5 to refresh the whole browser, again, getting the query parameter at the first time, then could not get it.

nuxt version:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "nuxt": "^3.7.4"
  },
```

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Do you `watch` it? What do you see in your devtools?

Comment: did you see the answer? down. is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked that out with nuxt 3.7.4. Do like this:

in your app.vue

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <!-- some page content -->
    <input type="search" v-model="q" />

    <nuxt-link :to="{path: '/search', query: {qry: q}}">Search</nuxt-link>

    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
<script setup>
const q = ref('')
</script>
```

and in your search.vue

```
<template>
    <p>{{ route.query.qry }}</p>
</template>
<script setup>

const route = useRoute()
console.log(route.query.qry);
watch(
  () => route.query.qry,
  () => {
    console.log(route.query.qry);
  },
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I test your code, but it works fine，here is the test project: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ecstatic-germain-gvtz6c?welcome=true